# Use custom profile on Zalenium to enable DRM

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, zalenium, firefox-profile

I am trying to create a custom firefox profile for a **remote driver** for a Selenium test. Technologies used:

- Written in Java
- Zalenium [link-to-zalenium](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/)

  ```
      File profileDirectory = new File("path-to-firefox-profile");
      FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);
      FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
      firefoxOptions.setProfile(profile);
      WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(http://localhost:4444/wd/hub, firefoxOptions);
  ```

This does not start the tests videos on Zalenium at all, but hangs.
Is this the correct way to create the remote driver? The reason why im using the custom profile is because I want to have **DRM** enabled when starting the tests,as the tests display videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution to enable DRM on the remote driver

```
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.addPreference("media.eme.enabled",true);
        firefoxOptions.addPreference("media.gmp-manager.updateEnabled", true);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://grid:4444/wd/hub", firefoxOptions);
```